# 23.10 with TPM-FDE shuts down during suspend

Tags: suspend

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 with TPM-FDE enabled on a Dell laptop. Occasionally when attempting to wake the device from suspend, it will perform a cold boot (i.e. it seems to have shutdown during suspend.)

Checking the end of journald from last boot I see only the following:

```
Jan 03 16:01:30 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 chronyd[1793]: Source 172.16.1.100 offline
Jan 03 16:01:30 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 chronyd[1793]: Source 172.21.1.100 offline
Jan 03 16:01:30 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 chronyd[1793]: Source 172.18.1.100 offline
Jan 03 16:01:30 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 chronyd[1793]: Can't synchronise: no selectable sources
Jan 03 16:01:30 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 chronyd[1793]: Source 185.125.190.57 offline
Jan 03 16:01:30 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 rtkit-daemon[1989]: Successfully made thread 4432 of process 4403 owned by '8046' high priority at nice level 0.
Jan 03 16:01:30 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 rtkit-daemon[1989]: Supervising 3 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Jan 03 16:01:30 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 wpa_supplicant[1435]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Jan 03 16:01:30 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 wpa_supplicant[1435]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Jan 03 16:01:30 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 wpa_supplicant[1435]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp0s20 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jan 03 16:01:30 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1704297690.926:1662): pid=1331 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor=>
                                            exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Jan 03 16:01:31 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 wpa_supplicant[1435]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Jan 03 16:01:31 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 wpa_supplicant[1435]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Jan 03 16:01:31 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 wpa_supplicant[1435]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp0s20f3 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jan 03 16:01:31 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 rtkit-daemon[1989]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jan 03 16:01:31 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 rtkit-daemon[1989]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jan 03 16:01:31 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 rtkit-daemon[1989]: Successfully made thread 4432 of process 4403 owned by '8046' RT at priority 20.
Jan 03 16:01:31 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 rtkit-daemon[1989]: Supervising 3 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Jan 03 16:01:32 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 systemd[1]: Reached target sleep.target - Sleep.
Jan 03 16:01:32 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Jan 03 16:01:32 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 systemd-sleep[31419]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
```

The systemd-suspend logs from the previous day:

```
Jan 03 14:24:27 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Jan 03 14:24:27 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 systemd-sleep[8901]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Jan 03 14:25:19 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 systemd-sleep[8901]: System returned from sleep state.
Jan 03 14:25:19 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 03 14:25:19 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 systemd[1]: Finished systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend.
Jan 03 16:01:32 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Jan 03 16:01:32 ubu-n-b5c04f594433 systemd-sleep[31419]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
```

I don't know what else to check here